# Affine coordinate ring, k- vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let
$$
  P_1 = (0, 0), \quad
  P_2 = (1, 0), \quad
  P_3 = (0, 1), \quad
  P_4 = (1, 1).
$$
Let $Y = \{P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4\}$ and
let $I \subset k[x, y]$ be the ideal of $Y$ .

1. Show that the affine coordinate ring $A(Y) = k[x, y]/I$ of Y has dimension $4$ as $k$-vector space.
2. Show that $I = (f, g)$, where $f = x^2 − x$ and $g = y^2 − y$.
   Hint: show that $(f, g) \subseteq I$, then that
   $(1, x, y, xy)$ gives a k-basis for $k[x, y]/(f, g)$ using divisions with remainder, then that the natural morphism $k[x, y]/(f, g) \to A(Y)$ is an isomorphism.

For question 1 I think that a $k$-algebra morphism
$$
  k[x, y] \to k^4,
  \qquad
  f \mapsto (f(P_1), f(P_2), f(P_3), f(P_4))
$$
will do the job but I am really lost with the structure of the spaces to form it.

Can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the coordinate ring is $k[x,y]/J$, where $J$ is the ideal
$$J=\langle x,y\rangle\cap\langle x-1,y\rangle \cap\langle x,y-1\rangle\cap \langle x-1,y-1\rangle,$$
which is equal to $k[x,y]/\langle x^2-x,y^2-y\rangle$.
See [Showing that two ideals are equivalent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375369/showing-that-two-ideals-are-equivalent/3375444#3375444) for more details.

Moreover, the standard monomial basis of $k[x,y]/J$ consists of $1,x,y,xy$ and so the coordinate ring is 4-dimensional over $k$.

Comment: Yes but for the first question we don't know the form of ideal I we just know that is an ideal in Y. I mean how can we show that k[x,y]/J  equals to k[x,y]/I  since we don't know I. Sorry that I am not getting it but I need more help with these terms

Comment: @CeliaKardamitsi: Should be clear by the link.